# How is Amon able to revoke someone's bending?

Tags: avatar

It was never fully explained how, despite him being a great water bender and blood bender, how was Amon able to remove someone's bending?

That ability was reserved, up until then, to energy bending, which only Avatar Aang could use.

What kind of technique did Amon use?

Comment: I think it was explained somehow. I don't remember exactly now, but the idea is that blood bending allows him to do something similar as qi-blocking but in a more permanent way.
He didn't really take away the bending, just gave this impression.

Answer (score 8):

As per this [link](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodbending) Bloodbending has a lot of potential to be used in specific ways. One of the effects is Bending severing :

> **Bending severing** :
>
> Bloodbending can be used to completely cut off a bender from his or her bending abilities, achieving the same effect as [energybending](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Energybending). This technique has only been demonstrated by Amon and requires direct physical contact between the user's hand and the victim's forehead. The effects of this technique are long-standing, and, unlike [chi blocking](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Chi_blocking), it cannot be easily undone. According to Katara, the technique "severs" an individual from his or her bending, making it impervious to all methods of healing. Even so, only active chi pathways can be severed; Korra was able to use airbending because it was still dormant when her other bending abilities were removed. However, the severed bending can be restored through the use of energybending, as shown by Aang and Korra